# i cannot get the GCM ID in Android in one app

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, public

[Solved but I still want an answer for the last question please, the problem was I was using capital letters instead of lower I let the code so other can correct errors]

I have tried some forum pages and searched through stackoverflow for the same thing, but I did not find the solution.

I have 2 apps that use the push messages, One app works great but the other one doesn't, I registered 2 times in Google so I get 2 different Api keys and 2 different Senders ID, if i switch the Senders ID I still didn't get the ID on the app that doesn't work(but it work on the app that works great), it never trigger onRegistered function

My manifest

```
    <permission android:name=""com.sexolia.sexyAsiaticas.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="normal" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sexolia.sexyAsiaticas.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

My receiver

```
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.sexolia.sexyasiaticas" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

My Service

```
 <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

My register Function

```
public void registrarGcm(Context ctx)
{
      String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(ctx);
        if (regId.equals("")) 
        {
            GCMRegistrar.register(ctx, "795463622136"); //Sender ID
        } 
}
```

Constructor

```
        public GCMIntentService() {
    super("795463622136");
}
```

Also, I will like to know, how I can decide  which app send the push message(is the api key,sender id or what?)? when 1 user is registered on the Google, it have different GCM id for the different applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer for your last question is that each application that registers for GCM receives a different Registration ID, even when the apps are running on the same device. This means that based on the Registration ID you use to send the message, GCM will know which app sends the message.

BTW, you can use the same Sender ID (aka Google API Project ID) and API Key in both of your apps for registering to GCM and sending the messages. You'd still get different Registration IDs for each app.